# Jquery ajax Method is Undefined

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I'm trying to pass data to the server with ajax.

Since jquery has the .ajaxStop event, that will be called when all ajax methods have completed, I need to change regular js code to jquery since it won't work with regular js.

Problem is every time I run the jquery code, in the browsers console I get this error.

```
'PassDataToServer' is not defined
```

C# Code

```cs
 [WebMethod]
    public static string PassDataToServer(String id, String clientData)
    {
        if (!dynamicInputs.ContainsKey(id))
            dynamicInputs.Add(id, clientData);
        else
            dynamicInputs[id] = clientData;

        return "complete";
    }
```

Old Regular JS

```js
function CallPassDataToServer(id, clientData) {
    PageMethods.PassDataToServer(id, clientData, onTransferComplete, onTransferFailed);
}
```

Jquery Failing Method

```js
function PassInputDataToServer(id, inputData)
{
    alert(document.URL + "/" + PassDataToServer);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: document.URL + "/" + PassDataToServer,
        data: { "id": "'" + id + "'", "clientData": "'" + inputData + "'" },
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: "text",
        success: function (result) { transferStatus.push(result); },
        error: function (result) { transferStatus.push("failed"); },
        complete: function (result) { transfersCompleted++; }       
    });
}
```

Comment: Don't see anywhere that `PassDataToServer` is defined as noted in the error

Comment: That function works fine, but I don't know of an easy way to wait for them all to finish. It calls it about 6 times, but by the time my postback function is called, only 4 have finished.
I only started getting the undefined error when I started calling the jquery function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the method to call as string

```
function PassInputDataToServer(id, inputData)
{
    alert(document.URL + "/" + "PassDataToServer"); // <----
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: document.URL + "/" + "PassDataToServer",   // <----
        data: { "id":  id, "clientData": inputData},
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) { transferStatus.push(result); },
        error: function (result) { transferStatus.push("failed"); },
        complete: function (result) { transfersCompleted++; }       
    });
}
```

Comment: Sorry did you just change the datatype to text?
I just edited it about a minute ago, it was json.
Unfortunately it still doesn't work.

Comment: Ok nevermind I see now. It is posting back but all the ajax functions are coming back as failed. I'll do some more investigating.

Comment: I don't get the undefined error, but it still doesn't seem to be calling the method. Any ideas?

Thanks though.

Comment: @LittleRain changed to datatype json and different format for data. Does that work? Have you checked that the URL is correct?

Comment: Yep that was it. Thanks a lot man! I'd up vote you if I could.